# On the global sections of a twisted line bundle over an algebraic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $L$ be a line bundle on a complex algebraic curve $C$. Let's assume that $H^0(L(-P)) =0$, for some $P \in C$.

Then my question is : Under this assumption on $L$ is it always true that $H^0(L(-nP)) =0,  \forall n \in \mathbb N$ ?

Let if possible $H^0(L(-2P)) \neq 0$, then we have an injection $\mathcal O_C \hookrightarrow L(-2P)$, then twisting this injection wtith $\mathcal O_C(P)$, we obtain $\mathcal O_C \hookrightarrow \mathcal O_C(P) \hookrightarrow L(-P)$, a contradiction to the assumption.

Please correct me if the above justification is wrong.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: The notation $L(-n)$ does not make sense. Do you mean $L(-nP)$ for some $P\in C$ ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, But is $L(-nP)$ for some $P \in C$ not same as $L\otimes \mathcal O_C(-n)$?.

Comment: My point is that the notation $\mathcal O_C(-n)$ does not make sense.What do you think it means?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, For me $\mathcal O_C(-n)$ is the line bundle corresponding to the divisor $-nP$, for some point $P \in C$. I wrote it that way because for a projective variety of arbitrary dimension we write $\mathcal O_X(-n)$ is the line bundle corresponding to $-nD$ for some divisor $D$ of $X$. Please correct me If I am making a fundamental mistake.

Comment: Your mistake is that $\mathcal O_C(-nP)$ and $\mathcal O_C(-nQ)$ will not be isomorphic in general if $P\neq Q$.  So your notation which does not say which $P$ you choose is meaningless.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, thanks a lot for pointing out. I will edit the question accordingly. What happens if the variety has dimension more than $2$?